# Android application installation

Tags: android

I have developed an application and installed it on my mobile. but i am seeing two icons with the same application name where one is stopping unexpectedly and another is working fine. Is it a serious issue? IF yes , what is the fix for it.The application changes the focus on set of buttons periodically,and using a select button the text of the button currently having focus is selected. Now i need to add audio interface so that when the focus is on a particular button it need to be spoken to the user. Please tell me the ways to accomplish it. Any sample source codes/ links are appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two kind of issue (as I can guess).

1. You have changed your app package name, installed app with new package and doesn't removed old one. In this case you need to remove both of them and install your app again.
2. You have provided more than one activites as launchers (`android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`) in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. One of them is buggy and crashes as you described. For this situation you need to remove some "unnecessary" launchers from your manifest.

Please provide more information, otherwise I've already done my best…

Comment: so the <category> launcher line should be deleted??do i need to delete as well the intent.action.Main line as well...

Comment: Yes, you need delete all section `<intent-filter>`, but it'll better if you show your `AndroidManifest.xml`, otherwise you can add some more crashes to yuor app =)

Comment: thanks man, it worked out. i have deleted the entire <intent filter> section.i dont know the exact purpose of it and the fields inside it. because i had to start another activity i have placed it in the manifest file.

Comment: do u have any idea how  to add audio interface for my application??

Comment: It'll be better if you ask this in separate question, cause it'is not connected with original problem; even if somebody helps you with audio in this thread, it'll be very hard to reuse this knowledge by people, who'll be used to deal with such problems as you did.